# Public Geoserver preview via third-party website?

Tags: geoserver, map-service, basemap

A few years ago I remember seeing a website that would connect to a public Geoserver offering and allow you to preview all available layers overlaid on a Google Maps or similar base layer.  Does anyone else remember that?  Is it still around somewhere?